# Canvas jitters half my rendering

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was working on a fun project that implicates creating "imperfect" circles by drawing them with lines and animate their points to generate a pleasing effect.

The points should alternate between moving away and closer to the center of the circle, to illustrate:

[image: graphic representation of the idea]

I think I was able to accomplish that, the problem is when I try to render it in a canvas half the render jitters like crazy, you can see it in this [**demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/oaxmz7sd/)

You can see how it renders for me in [**this video**](https://vid.me/dQ4B). If you pay close attention the bottom right half of the render runs smoothly while the top left just..doesn't.

This is how I create the points:

```
for (var i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    var a = toRad(aDiv * i);
    var e = rand(this.e, 1);
    var x = Math.cos(a) * (this.r * e) + this.x;
    var y = Math.sin(a) * (this.r * e) + this.y;
    this.points.push({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        initX: x,
        initY: y,
        reverseX: false,
        reverseY: false,
        finalX: x + 5 * Math.cos(a),
        finalY: y + 5 * Math.sin(a)
    }); 
}
```

Each point in the imperfect circle is calculated using an angle and a random distance that it's not particularly relevant (it relies on a few parameters).

I think it's starts to mess up when I assign the final values (`finalX,finalY`), the animation is supposed to alternate between those and their initial values, but only half of the render accomplishes it.

Is the math wrong? Is the code wrong? Or is it just that my computer can't handle the rendering?

I can't figure it out, thanks in advance!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oaxmz7sd/1/ ?

Comment: @guest271314 now it just kinda pulsates akwardly for me hahahaha

Comment: Not certain what expected effect is ?

Comment: well the points should alternate between their final and initial positions smoothly, but as I can't see how it renders on your side it's hard for me to elaborate hahah sorry!

Comment: @guest271314 here is a video of [**how it works for me**](https://vid.me/dQ4B), the bottom right corner looks fine, everything else sucks haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the math wrong? Is the code wrong? Or is it just that my computer can't handle the rendering?

I Think that your animation function has not care about the elapsed time. Simply the animation occurs very fast. The number of [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) callbacks is usually 60 times per second, So Happens just what is expected to happen.

I made some fixes in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/jpgk685o/). This animate function take care about timestamp. Also I made a gradient in the animation to alternate between their final and initial positions smoothly.

```
ImperfectCircle.prototype.animate = function (timestamp) {
    var factor = 4;
    var stepTime = 400;
    for (var i = 0, l = this.points.length; i < l; i++) {
        var point = this.points[i];
        var direction = Math.floor(timestamp/stepTime)%2;
        var stepProgress = timestamp % stepTime * 100 / stepTime;
        stepProgress = (direction == 0 ? stepProgress: 100 -stepProgress);
        point.x = point.initX + (Math.cos(point.angle) * stepProgress/100 * factor); 
        point.y = point.initY + (Math.sin(point.angle) * stepProgress/100 * factor);
    }
}
```

#### Step by Step:

*based on comments*

```
// 1. Calculates the steps as int: Math.floor(timestamp/stepTime)
// 2. Modulo to know if even step or odd step: %2
var direction = Math.floor(timestamp/stepTime)%2;

// 1. Calculates the step progress: timestamp % stepTime
// 2. Convert it to a percentage: * 100 / stepTime
var stepProgress = timestamp % stepTime * 100 / stepTime;

// if odd invert the percentage. 
stepProgress = (direction == 0 ? stepProgress: 100 -stepProgress);

// recompute position based on step percentage
// factor is for fine adjustment.
point.x = point.initX + (Math.cos(point.angle) * stepProgress/100 * factor); 
point.y = point.initY + (Math.sin(point.angle) * stepProgress/100 * factor);
```

Comment: It works perfectly! (looks much more elegant too) Though I would really like it if you could explain it step by step, as I'm not big on math hahah, thanks in advance!

Comment: @undefined I added some details about the math.